# Ubuntu 20.04 and Ubuntu 16.04 accessing ext4 drives differently?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

I recently did a upgrade and I have been troubling building a game project in Unreal. My basic setup is a 250gig ssd with Ubuntu 16.04 standard ext4. I upgraded it with a 1 terabyte ssd with Ubuntu 20.04. I have a mechanical regular hard drive with programs and other data files that is a 2 terabyte hard drive with ext4 format.

The issue when building a project is Unreal Engine is on the 2 terabyte hard drive along with data files. I can build a project using Unreal when I have the old ssd installed. If I swap to the new ssd, Unreal Engine can't build a project. Me and a developer, think although the 2 terabyte drive is ext4, Ubuntu 20.04 and 16.04 are accessing the hard drive differently causing problems creating issues for Unreal.

It's a assumption and only the thing I can think of.  Am I incorrect or that's accurate?

Comment: There is an incomplete amount of information here to answer your question. Are there any *specific* error messages that can be shared? Do the system logs show any errors when booting or mounting other hard drives? Linux is usually pretty good about complaining when people do things ...

Comment: No error. The OS loads correctly and no errors in the system log. The error I have is when I build a project in Unreal depending on the sdd/OS. One instance Unreal builds a project when the 16.04 os/ssd is used but if I use the 20.04 os/ssd. Unreal does not build. Basically, there is a cook process that accesses all the files. Either the non-ssd hd hangs at a point, errors about drive being slow to access data, or the computer just becomes unresponsive.

Comment: Both process uses the same files and directory structure. I did a hard drive check and memory check both computer and gpu. So, technically the last option I can think of is the OS accessing the hard drive just a little different. Enougth to hang Unreal. The upgraded 20.04 has the latest video driver Nvidia 4.60 while the older version is 4.16 with a Nvida GTX 1660 but that should not be a issue.

Comment: I doubt this is anything to do with two versions of Ubuntu accessing ext4 drives differently. It could be a hardware problem or even something to do with the way you set up the new drive like having the correct block alignment. If you cloned from 256GB to 1TB that is a possibility. The driver you mentioned could also be the culprit

Comment: The 1 terabyte ssd was a fresh install. So, I can install a different video driver and see what happens.

Comment: I only say that Ponjar is because when I install the 16.04 ssd. My projects build and cook okay with the same hardware. I was able to build and cook some of the same projects 20.04 but it was parts of it. Always got stuck doing the cook part compiling shaders. So, it's either a driver if Unreal uses the gpu driver to compute shaders or some other circular loop.